# Parsing yaml files with yaml-cpp

Tags: c++, yaml, wxwidgets, yaml-cpp

I'm having problem with parsing `yaml` files using `yaml-cpp`, I'm making a application using `wxWidgets` and I'm trying to read the frame size from a `yaml` file which looks like,

```
---
This is the configuration file for the Sample Browser,
feel free to edit this file as needed
...

Window:
  SizeW: 1280
  SizeH: 720
Media:
  Autoplay: false
```

And this the code that should handle the parsing,

```
    int sizeH, sizeW;

    try
    {
        YAML::Node config = YAML::LoadFile("/home/apoorv/repos/cpp-projects/wxWidgets/SampleBrowser/build/config.yaml");

        if (!config["Window"])
        {
            wxLogDebug("Error! Cannot fetch values.");
        }

        sizeH = config["SizeH"].as<int>();
        sizeW = config["SizeW"].as<int>();
    }

    catch(const YAML::ParserException& ex)
    {
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }

    this->SetSize(sizeW, sizeH);
```

But when I try to parse this file and set the frame size `this->SetSize()` it errors out saying `*** Caught unhandled unknown exception; terminating`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `SizeH` and `SizeW` are children of `Window`, your two lines should look like

```cpp
    sizeH = config["Window"]["SizeH"].as<int>();
    sizeW = config["Window"]["SizeW"].as<int>();
```

or, merged with the previous check,

```cpp
    if (auto window = config["Window"]) {
        sizeH = window["SizeH"].as<int>();
        sizeW = window["SizeW"].as<int>();
    } else {
        wxLogDebug("Error! Cannot fetch values.");
    }
```

Generally, the error handling is bad. In your code, if an error is encountered, `sizeH` and `sizeW` are not set *but are still given to `SetSize`*. This is undefined behavior. You should initialize them with some default values, e.g.

```cpp
int sizeH = 480, sizeW = 640;
```

Also, since you keep us in the dark about what `this` is, there may be other errors.

Comment: I tried the code you shared above, the both with and with `if`, also initialized the `int sizeW` and `int sizeH` but I'm still getting the same error. `this` is `wxFrame` as I'm inside the class `MainFrame` which inherits from `wxFrame`.

Comment: I think the problem that I'm having now is because in my `yaml` file, the first 4 lines are doc, and I'm straight away asking for a key, is there a way to ignore the the doc in the beginning, or skip past it? Because if I delete those first 4 lines, it works.

Comment: @apoorv569 I overlooked that. The first four lines are indeed another YAML document. You'll need to do `config = YAML::LoadAllFromFile("…/config.yaml")[1];` to get the second YAML document which contains your values.

Comment: Changing it from `LoadFile()` to `LoadAllFromFile()` gives an error saying, `No viable conversion from std::vector<Node> to YAML::Node`. BTW is this doc in the beginning is like a comment, I added it as kind of a comment, or is it something else.

Comment: @apoorv569 You forgot the `[1]` in the end. And your first four lines are a YAML document starting with a directives end marker (`---`), containing a single scalar, and ending with a document end marker (`...`). They load as a YAML document containing a single scalar node. The following content creates a second YAML document, which is why you need to use `LoadAllFromFile`.

Comment: Oops, it works now after adding `[1]`. Ah! I see, so I think I should remove the doc and instead look for what function adds comments, because this is not what I wanted. Anyways thanks :D

Comment: @apoorv569 `#` is the comment characters for YAML. Your method of commenting does make sense only if you want to read the comment into a C++ string (YAML comments with `#` get thrown away in the parser, you can't access them in your code).

Comment: I made this `yaml` file by using `YAML::Emitter`, the only reason I want to add comments is for documenting/instruction/help for user to see what key changes what, I don't want to parse the comments, I was for now using `YAML::BeginDoc` `YAML::EndDoc` block, I thought that's how you add comments, but I found `YAML::Comment` so I'm going to use this one instead.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine to try to do this for learning yaml-cpp, but if you really want to save/restore your frame geometry, you should use [wxPersistentTLW](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.4/classwx_persistent_t_l_w.html) instead. To use it, just call `wxPersistentRegisterAndRestore(frame, "NameToIdentifyYourFrame")` after creating your frame, see [the manual](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.4/overview_persistence.html) for more details.

Comment: Yes, I know about this, but the reason I'm using separate `yaml` file is, I want to be able to store much more than just the window size and position, I'm making kind of like a configuration file, where user can change some settings about the application.

Answer (score 0):

In the cross-platform environment it is better to save the client size of the window, as for GTK what's important is the client size. There might be other OSes/toolkits where this is the case.